# Transpile code with Babel 7 to be used in a Node12/Babel6 app

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm creating a package that will be rendering some React components (MDX to be precise) into a string, with `renderToStaticMarkup`.
I'm using Webpack + Babel 7 to transpile it.

Now I need to be able to consume this code from a legacy Node12/Babel6 app.
I get this error when I'm trying to do that:

`Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3".`

[image: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3".]

I don't understand why it happens. My package shouldn't need any babel runtime, it has import/export+async/await, all of it should transpile to Node12 without needing any runtime.

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: ['./src/index.ts'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: {
      type: 'commonjs2',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: '@mdx-js/loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "12"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": false
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's possible that your Babel 6 app is trying to compile this dependency using this Babel 7 .babelrc file. You can try renaming the .babelrc file to .babelrc.json so that it's not supported by Babel 6, or even better you can add it to .npmignore so that it's not published.

Comment: Whoa @Nicolò, that worked! Could you please provide it as an answer and I'll accept it.
Somehow I thought that Babel6 ignores everything in node_modules, so I didn't consider that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Babel 6 app probably passes your dependencies through Babel.

When compiling a file, the default Babel 6 behavior is to load the nearest `.babelrc` file and use it (this has been changed in Babel 7 - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading): your Babel 6 instance is reading the `.babelrc` file meant to be used by Babel 7, tries to load the Babel 7 plugins and throws.

A possible workaround is to rename `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.json`: it's not supported by Babel 6, so it will be ignored.

A proper solution, if we are talking about a published package, is to add `.babelrc` to your `.npmignore` file: by doing so it won't be present in your `node_modules`, so it won't be accidentally loaded by Babel 6.

Comment: Did both `.npmignore` and `.babelrc.json` tricks and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!